# why is this mysql query is not actually updating anything

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm no backend expert but I thought I had a pretty good grasp on PDO queries with mysql but for some reason I can't figure out why this statment doesn't seem to update anything in my database (though the condition is definately met in the db  )
anyways here is the statement:

```
    $update = "UPDATE content
    SET src_link=:src_link
    WHERE content_id=:content_id";
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($update);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content_id', $video['content_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':src_link', $video['src_link']);
    $stmt->execute();
```

some explanation the transaction is initiated earlier in a script, and this code is wrapped in a try catch with no catch being caught. the src_link is a var_char and content_id is a primary key  .. however I have printed out the video array and entered code like this which works in phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE `content` SET `src_link`= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3rMo5cgaXQ'
 WHERE `content_id`=6939
```

where these values were taken directly from an attempt output in my php script and seems to work

Anyways, I am kind of lost to why this is not working and have been stuck on this for the last couple hours and without resolving I can't move forward so any help with how I can get the pdo to properly output would be greatly appreciated as I have about a 1000+ updates to put in . 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you committing the transaction?

Comment: Is PDO set to throw exceptions?

Comment: Have you tried defining the data types? $stmt->bindParam(':content_id', $video['content_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT)); //PDO::PARAM_STR for the string type. Also - what is the result of the bindParam() methods and the execute() method?

Comment: PDO is set to throw exceptiions yani  i have not tried this and @Barmar no ... I think the commit is what I am missing

Comment: @Barmar if you want to copy and past your comment into an answer I'll accept it ... dumb mistake on my part but thanks for the pair of obvious eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've started a transaction, you have to commit the transaction to make the changes permanent.